# How to make a bottom sheet not hideable but still draggable downwards even with a peek height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want my bottom sheet to not be hideable but still be draggable downwards. Whenever I set a peek height it seems that the bottom sheet is no longer draggable below that height. Is this possible?

isDraggable is set to true and behavior_hideable is set to false. The peek height is being set to 60% of the screen height.